# EF 7 Database datetime generated value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this model

```
 public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CommentId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastEditedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to let the db generate the value of `CreatedAt` and `LastEditedAt`  so in my `OnModelCreating` method  of my `DbContext` I used

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(c =>
            {
                c.Property(p => p.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                c.Property(p => p.LastEditedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            });
```

When trying to insert I get an inner exception in `SaveChanges()` saying

```
{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedAt', table 'WX.dbo.Comment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."}
```

Does that mean that I have to assign values to those two columns manually?

Fixed by making `LastEditedAt` nullable

```
 public DateTime  CreatedAt { get; set; }
 public DateTime? LastEditedAt { get; set; }
```

and setting an SQL default value to `CreatedAt`

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(c =>
            {
                c.Property(p => p.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
                c.Property(p => p.LastEditedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set DateTime to nullable : `DateTime?`.

Comment: I set the CreatedAt default falue to "GETUTCDATE()" and LastEditedAt as you said thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help! Can you show us the fixed code? Just curious. :)

Comment: Didn't know about the `HasDefaultValueSql()`, nice to know, tks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following solution to be able to set value to the creation and modification date fields:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleEntity>(c =>
{
   c.Property(p => p.CreatedDate).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
   c.Property(p => p.UpdatedDate).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
});
```

You should look this issues on EntityFrameworkCore github repository:

[Issue3955](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3955)

[Issue4501](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4501)

In those links shows several ways to solve the generation problem of create/update date fields.